# Visual Studio Code .NET Core - Launch (web) does not start the browser

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to debug a .NET Core WebApi application on Red Hat Linux. But when I press F5 I get the following in the DEBUG CONSOLE and the browser does not start. Thank You

Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[4657] TodoApi.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

here's what's in the launch.json file

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/TodoApi.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open http://localhost:5000/api/values"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place 'http://localhost:5000/api/values' within the `"args"` section instead of appending to the `"command"` section.

So the code, in your case, will be something like:

```
"linux": {
    "command": "xdg-open",
    "args": "http://localhost:5000/api/values"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not make any difference.  Still the same problem

Comment: @Peter debugger still doesn't open the browser?

Comment: Correct, it does not open the browser.

Comment: @Peter have you figured this out I am having the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I've never gone back to Linux as of yet, but at some time I will have to.  Nothing with against Linux, just too many other projects.